# Send a post request with libcurl C++ question :s

Tags: c++, https, libcurl

I've succeeded in my GET request with libcurl, no problems!

However when I try to send a post request, I'm unsure of where I put the json data, I want to be sent over..

My code looks like this, and I wonder if there is a method where I can send over the data as is:

```
CURL* curlpost;

curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

curlpost = curl_easy_init();
if (curlpost) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curlpost, CURLOPT_URL, "https://127.0.0.1:50006/lol-lobby/v2/lobby");
    // post data:
    curl_easy_setopt(curlpost, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{

        "customGameLobby": {
        "configuration": {
            "gameMode": "CLASSIC", "gameMutator" : "", "gameServerRegion" : "",
                "mapId" : 11,
                "mutators" : {"id": 1}, "spectatorPolicy" : "AllAllowed", "teamSize" : 5
        }

    },
        "queueId": 830,
        "isCustom" : false
}")
```

That doesn't work and is the raw JSON data I want to send to the server.

How can I send that data to the server is my question?

JSON data to be sent:

```
{
"customGameLobby": {
    "configuration": {
      "gameMode": "CLASSIC",
      "gameMutator": "",
      "gameServerRegion": "",
      "mapId": 11, 
      "mutators": {"id": 1},
      "spectatorPolicy": "AllAllowed",
      "teamSize": 5 
    }
  },
"queueId": 830,
"isCustom": false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`curl_easy_escape`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_escape.html) to URL encode the given C string:

```
char* encoded = curl_easy_escape(curlpost, "{ your post data }", 0);

// use "encoded"

// free the memory
curl_free(encoded);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your input. When I try that and paste my post data in there, it gives me quite some errors, would you mind showing me how to pass it in correctly. The post data I wanna send, is in the question: "JSON data to be sent: {.... "

Thank you!

Comment: `curl_easy_setopt(curlpost, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, encoded);` or `curl_easy_setopt(curlpost,  CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS, encoded);` should work. Perhaps you need to supply a different content type with [`CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.html). You can see how that's done in this [example](https://gist.github.com/jay/2a6c54cc6da442489561)